# PHP code works with Safari but not with another browser

Tags: php, session, safari

I've got a quite big problem :/

In my code, the session variable `$_SESSION["questionAmount"]` has value 0 at the begining.
After having sent the form 
`<form method="post" action="#" name="formular" id="formular">
[...]
</form>`

it increases by 1. (`$_SESSION["questionAmount"]++;`)

Depending on the value of the session variable, I get different questions form a database.

(what I want: first question: session variable is 0, second question: session var is 1, third question: session var is 2 and finished). This all works perfectly using Safari.
But as soon as I use another browser, the second question will be skipped.

Oh, but it's getting even funnier! If I echo the session var, it will work fine, also in other browsers.

Has anyone any idea why this can happen?

Thank you in advance.

Here's the main part of the code:

```
<?php

session_set_cookie_params(86400, '/', '...');
session_name('...');
session_start();

//It's about this session variable
//before having redirecting to this page, the Session variable had been set to -1
$_SESSION["questionAmount"]++;


if ($_SESSION["questionAmount"] == 3) {
    header('Location: /thankyou.php');
}

//connecting to database

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE `id` = '".$_SESSION["questionAmount"]."';"; 

//executing $sql

//work something WITHOUT using or changing the session var
```

?>

```
<form method="post" action="#" name="Formular" id="form_source">
                <fieldset>
                    <div id="question_wrapper">
                        <p id="question_question" style="display: none;"><?php echo $question; ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <p id="place"></p>
                    <div id="submit1_div" style="padding: 5px;">
                        <button id="submit1" name="answer" value="answer1" style="display: none;"><?php echo $answer1; ?></button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="submit2_div" style="padding: 5px;">
                        <button id="submit2" name="answer" value="answer2" style="display: none;"><?php echo $answer2; ?></button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="submit3_div" style="padding: 5px;">
                        <button id="submit3" name="answer" value="answer3" style="display: none;"><?php echo $answer3; ?></button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="submit4_div" style="padding: 5px;">
                        <button id="submit4" name="answer" value="answer4" style="display: none;"><?php echo $answer4; ?></button>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Comment: Show us full code.

Comment: Impossible. PHP is server-side and *does not care what browser is used*.

Comment: Yes, that's why I don't understand it... because it's actually impossible

Comment: I'll post the code in a minute.

Comment: could it be a mechanism in the browsers that call the server twice? e.g. chrome sends a request to `favico`. can't you use a hidden input or something?

Comment: @Webinan Yes, you might be right! By clicking on a button, Chrome and Opera require the site twice. One time with status 200 and the other time with status 302. By contrast, Safari requires the site only once. By the way, if you didn't press any button, in 13 seconds the page would refresh using `header('refresh: 13; url=#');`.

Comment: I've just tried it another time. If I echo the session var, it will also work perfectly in other browsers. Well, that's now the end of my php code with which everything works: `mysqli_close($connection); echo $_SESSION['questionAmount']; header('refresh: 13; url=#');`. With this end it didn't work: `mysqli_close($connection); header('refresh: 13; url=#');`. And, @Webinan, you're totally right. With the other code the other browsers require the page just once. Strange, isn't it? Is there another chance of getting it working without having to echo the session var?

Comment: check the network tab in chrome dev tools to see the requests, if it is is favico, you can put an icon there so that your php does not respond